# Error: 'You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type' when building react-static site

Tags: reactjs, react-static

I got this error when building the site with react-static:

> ERROR in
>   ERROR in C:/Users/.../test/artifacts/react-static-templates.js 1:1016
>   C:/Users/.../test/artifacts/react-static-templates.js
>   1:1016 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:1016) You may need an
>   appropriate loader to handle this file type.

The site was just created. I can run it but i can't build for deploy.

This seams to be a problem with babel loader but i don't know enough about the react-static architecture to fix it.

Here the config files i think may maybe relevant:

**file: .babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["react-static/babel-preset.js"]
}
```

**file: .eslintrc.js**

```
module.exports = {
  extends: 'react-tools',
}
```

**file:package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react-static-example-basic",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-static start",
    "stage": "react-static build --staging",
    "build": "react-static build",
    "bundle": "react-static bundle",
    "export": "react-static export",
    "serve": "serve dist -p 3000 -s"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@reach/router": "^1.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "react": "^16.8.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.3.12",
    "react-static": "^6.0.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-config-react-tools": "1.x.x",
    "serve": "10.1.1"
  }
}
```

Environment:

- nodejs : v10.15.3
- npm : 6.9.0
- react-static: 6.3.6

**Update 2019-03-16:**

Made a lite progress. Found this closed [issue](https://github.com/nozzle/react-static/issues/1017) that match perfectly this error.

Still, after applying the fix, build of the static template fails but now with the error message:

```
ERROR in .../artifacts/react-static-templates.js
Module build failed (from ./babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be more appropriate to post as an issue in the project's issue tracker?

Comment: Maybe. I found many posts here due to broken releases. Anyway I am also trying help from then. I am not sure what is the cause, my reinstall or broken release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem on my mac, by cleaning complete the nodejs environment and installing it all again.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x) the steps.
Look at the comments too. 
It can be a few more steps on comments.